# Convert 'undefined' to undefined - JavaScript

Tags: javascript, string, type-conversion

How can I convert 'undefined' which is of type String to undefined of type undefined

Comment: The real question is where is that string coming from in the first place? Most likely it's coming from something that is of the type `undefined` and you are seeing that converted to a string.

Comment: its coming from query string @ScottMarcus

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just check and change.

```
if (s === 'undefined') s = undefined;
```